# rails sendgrid send email in schedule time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, schedule, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid to sent email in ror application. my doubt is we can compose a email now and the email must deliver to the user in particular  schedule time,  which given by user at time of compose.

for Eg.

From : xxxx@gmail.com

to : yyyy@gmail.com

Subject : Hi

Message : How are you ?

Msg Deliver time : 05-11-2014 7.30 pm

is it any option for this in  sendgrid  (or)                                           we want to store that details in db and use cronjob for this is only solution ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If your window is under 24 hours, you can use SendGrid's [SMTP-API Scheduling Parameters](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/scheduling_parameters.html). You supply a unix timestamp with when you would like the email delivered.

From the docs:

```
{
  "send_at": 1409348513
}
```

If your window exceeds 24 hours, a worker / cron is most likely the best solution.

Comment: Hi                                                                      mail = SendGrid::Mail.new                                                   mail.send_at = 1415149020                                                it show errors NoMethodError: undefined method `send_at=' for #<SendGrid::Mail:0x9359a90>

Comment: Hi there Paul,  The :send_at param is used through our SMTPAPI Headers.  You can use it like the following:

`header = Smtpapi::Header.new
sendtime = Time.local(2014, 10, 05, 17, 56, 35)
header.set_send_at(send time)`